# How to open log window in QTikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors

Unluckily for me, I close the log window in QTikZ (small window which stand below main editor window). Does anybody know how to open it again?. I try with `View -> View Log` but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Settings -> Sidebars -> Messages
```